# screen orientation in Android Fragments

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have one `fragment` in my android app. When I rotate my screen into `landscape`, it is displaying in half screen and remaining screen is filled by a blank space. How to avoid it?

I have declared in `manifest.xml` as **`android:configchanges="orientation|screensize`

My XML consists of a radiogroup,checkbox group and buttons.

Comment: I think that we need more information, put xml file of that screen. I think you are settings the layout with values and you are not using match_parent values. Give us more information.

Comment: What happens when you remove the configchanges attribute in your manifest? What is the reason you use it?

Comment: if I remove configchanges, My screen is automatically moving into next screen.It is a screen which consists of questions. If I click button, then only it should move.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very specific need, don't use `android:configchanges`. This causes your fragment to not be destroyed automatically and you would have to handle the changes that should happen after the screen orientation change manually in `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

It's best to let your activities and fragments to be destroyed and re-created when screen orientation changes. This will also handle the layout display for different screen orientations.

See more on that topic in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config). There's even a note on using `android:configchanges`:

> Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Comment: I want to override the method in all the fragments and activities?

Comment: If you still want to use `android:configchanges`, you would have to if you need to make any changes.

Comment: If I write config changes, the screen becomes half . Remaining is blank space.

Answer (score 0):

When the orientation changes the Activity is destroyed and recreated. The method you would override if using **configChanges** is **onConfigurationChanged**.